# jQuery got no function after AJAX call

Tags: layered-navigation, jquery

I'm having a problem in using horizontal navigation. When I sort something, at I changes show products with ajax the navigation isn't functional anymore. The click function in jQuery is still working but **removeClass** and **addClass** isn't working anymore.

The click function in our jQuery (ajaxlist module):

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#horizontal-layered-navigation-container div.horizontal-filter .filter-title", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    _is_expanded = jQuery(this).hasClass("horizontal-filter-title-expanded");
    jQuery("#horizontal-layered-navigation-container div.horizontal-filter .filter-title.horizontal-filter-title-expanded, #horizontal-layered-navigation-container div.horizontal-filter .filter-content.horizontal-filter-content-expanded").removeClass('horizontal-filter-title-expanded horizontal-filter-content-expanded');
    if (!_is_expanded) {
        jQuery(this).next('div.filter-content').addClass('horizontal-filter-content-expanded');
        jQuery(this).addClass('horizontal-filter-title-expanded');
    }
    window._open_horizontal_dropdown = true;
});
```

Link when sorting works: /mand and after ajaxcall and sorting is broken /mand#brands=701,419,882

Hope some of you can figure out why the body of the if-statement suddenly isn't working :)

Comment: Tell me if you need anything else then the jquery click-function

Comment: Is your if condition working?

Comment: Its seems like it is. And _is_expanded is set, but forgot after each click

Comment: The question cannot be reproduced, that's why no answer is coming, please be precise of what you want, then only some one can give answer to you

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran the if-statement is working. Its printing a console.log inside the ifstatement. Link when sorting works: /mand and after ajaxcall and sorting is broken /mand#brands=701,419,882

Comment: @KevinSteenHansen , is `_is_expanded` a global variable?

Comment: is it something that it is working for the first time and from second click it is not working ?

Comment: @KevinSteenHansen have you resolved this one?